# Disable Morris.js donut chart section selection on mouse hover event

Tags: hover, selection, morris.js, donut-chart

How to disable donut section selection of Morris.js chart on mouse hover event and allow selection only on chart section click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs for `Morris.Donut()`, it appears that this is not an option.

If you reallyyyy want to make it behave this way, you can dig into the `Morris.js` file itself. Modifying line 1918 (Morris.js on github) from:

```
seg.on('hover', this.select);
```

to:

```
seg.on('click', this.select);
```

This one line change will accomplish what you want as shown in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuox0e13/).

You will now have to distribute this version of Morris.js with your site. You will no longer be able to use their pre-minified version or a cdn though. You can however minify your new version yourself and distribute that.

Personally, I think this is sort of obnoxious and should be a configurable option in Morris.js

P.S. It has a BSD lisence but I'm no law expert. You should check with someone more knowledgeable about software lisencing before running this modified code in a production environment.